# Why are my if statements outputing the same thing as the first one?

Tags: c++

I have this code right here and I need your help on this.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    char red = ' ';
    char Red = ' ';
    char blue = ' ';
    char yellow = ' ';
    char white = ' ';
    char color1 = ' ';
    char color2 = ' ';

    // INPUT
    std::cout << "Enter a primary color (red, blue, yellow): ";
    std::cin >> color1;
    std::cout << std::endl; // For Mimir
    std::cout << "Enter a different primary color (red, blue, yellow): ";
    std::cin >> color2;
    std::cout << std::endl; // For Mimir

    if (color1 != red && color2 != blue) {
        std::cout << "red and blue make purple" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if (color1 != yellow && color2 != red) {
        std::cout << "yellow and red make orange" << std::endl;
    }

    if (color1 != blue && color2 != yellow) {
        std::cout << "yellow and blue make green" << std::endl;
    }

    if (color1 != Red && color2 != white) {
        std::cout << "You entered invalid colors";
    }
}
```

When I input yellow and blue and yellow and red for color1 and color2, I always get this:

```
Enter a primary color (red, blue, yellow): 
Enter a different primary color (red, blue, yellow): 
red and blue make purple
```

What am I doing wrong? Pls let me know.

Comment: `char red = ' '; char blue = ' ';`etc. All "colors" are initialized to a space. And whatever you input it will not be a space, and therefore not equal to any of the "colors".

Comment: Also `if(color1 != red && color2 != blue)` is true when `color1` is _not_ red and `color2` is _not_ blue. Is that what you want?

Comment: You ask the user to enter a color (red,blue,yellow) but use a char variable which can only store a single character.

Comment: On the prompt "Enter a primary color (red, blue, yellow): " I would enter probably "red", or "blue". But you seem to only expect a single letter, like "r" or "b".

Comment: If you enter `yellow`, `color1` is `'y'` and `color2` is `'e'`, so your first condition is `if ('y' != ' ' && 'e' != ' ')`. (You seem to be confused both about the difference between characters and strings, and the difference between strings and identifiers.)

Comment: Your purple case is different from the others in being the only one with a `return`. Are you aware of that? It makes the program leave early I think...

Comment: You need to go several steps back. Read a single input. Try to echo it. If you cannot do that all of the rest of the program is moot. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/ And debugging is something which would make your life so much easier: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

Your colors chars are all the same, they are initialized as a space char" ", so every letter you put in your console will be different from it.

Also, two important things.
The operator `!=` means "is not equal" and by looking at your code it seems you need a `==` operator on each `if` statement. So you need to change them.

Secondly, you should use an else-if statement, because if you remove `return` from the first condition you are going to check and print every `if` statement. So, you have two options: insert `return` in every if statement or, better, use an else-if structure.

If you make these changes your code will work as you want. My suggestions is to check just one or two conditions first, then you can go further with more code once you understand else-if structure and operators.

I'll give you a minimal code to understand, then try yourself to do more.

```
char red = 'r';

char blue= 'b';

//INPUT FROM CONSOLE

if (color1 == red && color2 == blue) {
        std::cout << "red and blue make purple" << std::endl;
}
else if (color1 == yellow && color2 == red){
        std::cout << "yellow and red make orange" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I tried what you did but all the test cases still show "You entered Invalid colors" as their output

Comment: i mean the test cases that are supposed to say "red and blue make purple". "yellow and red make orange", and "yellow and blue make green"

Comment: The variable color is a char. What do you input from the console? "red" or "r"?

Comment: If you input "red" in color 1 you are going to have "r" in color1 variable and "e" in color2 variable, that's your problem.